# read text from website

Tags: android

i work with the emulator and try to get a text from a website.The error of the alertdialog: "the application mainactivity has
stopped unexpectedly. Please try again".

```
    public void testr(View view) throws IOException, URISyntaxException 
  {
     URL websiteurl = new URL("http://test...");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
       websiteurl.openStream()));

   String inputLine;
   AlertDialog alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
   alertbox.setMessage(inputLine.toString());
   in.close();

 alertbox.show();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android 2.3 or later, then you are probably running into the situation that the OS kills all processes that do network IO in the UI thread, as you seem to do in the snippet above.

Put your network io in the background by e.g. using an `AsyncTask` for it. Have a look at the [docs for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
            URL url = new URL("website");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
        rbc = in;
```

Use this

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("mysite.com/thefile.txt");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
    }
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: I try the codes but it does not work. it is the same error "the application mainactivity has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again".I use android 2.2 with the emulator...what i have to do with async task?please give a example...